# Eigenspace dimension of a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $K$ be a compact operator on a Hilbert space $H$. By basic theory such that $K$ can have infinite dimensional kernel, but all other eigenspaces must have finite dimension. Is there a conceptual way to see why this is true?

Comment: Restricting $K$ to an eigenspace with eigenvalue $\lambda\neq0$ gives you the operator $\lambda I$, which is not compact if the eigenspace is not finite dimensional. In fact, take an orthonormal basis of the eigenspace, then its image is still orthonormal, and therefore no subsequence is convergent. Kernel can be infinite dimensional as you can see in the example $K(x)=(x,y)$ for some $y\neq0$ in an infinite dimensional $H$. This operator is compact, because if $\|x_n\|=1$ then $|T(x_n)|=|(x_n,y)|\leq\|y\|$ is a bounded sequence of numbers from which you can extract a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an argument I like: the restriction of any compact operator to a subspace should be compact.  However, the restriction of $K$ to the eigenspace $V$ associated with $\lambda$ is given by
$$
K|_V:V \to V\\
Kx = \lambda x
$$
If $\lambda \neq 0$, then the map $x \mapsto \lambda x$ is only compact if $V$ is finite dimensional.